# Custom 401 and 403 response model with UseJwtBearerAuthentication middleware

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-1.0

I want to respond with a JSON response model when a 401 and 403 occur. For example:

```
HTTP 401
{
  "message": "Authentication failed. The request must include a valid and non-expired bearer token in the Authorization header."
}
```

I am using middleware (as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278925/custom-404-response-model/38279498#38279498)) to intercept 404s and it works great, but it is not the case with 401 or 403s. Here is the middleware:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    await next();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 401)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(UnauthorizedModel.Create(), SerializerSettings), Encoding.UTF8);
    }
});
```

When placed BELOW `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(..)` in `Startup.Configure(..)`, it seems to be completely ignored and a normal 401 is returned.

When placed ABOVE `app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(..)` in `Startup.Configure(..)`, then the following exception is thrown:

> Connection id "0HKT7SUBPLHEM": An unhandled exception was thrown by
>   the application. System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are
>   read-only, response has already started.    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Internal.Http.FrameHeaders.Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.IHeaderDictionary.set_Item(String
>   key, StringValues value)    at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Internal.DefaultHttpResponse.set_ContentType(String
>   value)    at MyProject.Api.Startup.<b__12_0>d.MoveNext() in
>   Startup.cs

Answer (score 12):

Set was on the right track, but there's actually no need to create your own middleware, as you can leverage the events model to override the default challenge logic.

Here's an example that will return a 401 response containing the OAuth2 error code/description as plain text (you can of course return JSON or whatever you want):

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
{
    Authority = "http://localhost:54540/",
    Audience = "http://localhost:54540/",
    RequireHttpsMetadata = false,
    Events = new JwtBearerEvents
    {
        OnChallenge = async context =>
        {
            // Override the response status code.
            context.Response.StatusCode = 401;

            // Emit the WWW-Authenticate header.
            context.Response.Headers.Append(
                HeaderNames.WWWAuthenticate,
                context.Options.Challenge);

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Error))
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(context.Error);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.ErrorDescription))
            {
                await context.Response.WriteAsync(context.ErrorDescription);
            }

            context.HandleResponse();
        }
    }
});
```

Alternatively, you can also use the status code pages middleware, but for 403 responses, you won't have any hint about the authorization policy that caused it:

```
app.UseStatusCodePages(async context =>
{
    if (context.HttpContext.Request.Path.StartsWithSegments("/api") &&
       (context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 401 ||
        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode == 403))
    {
        await context.HttpContext.Response.WriteAsync("Unauthorized request");
    }
});
```

Comment: Ah, this works well for authentication! Although none of these events seem to trigger for an authorization failure (403). Any idea here?

Comment: Unfortunately, applying the same logic to 403 responses will be a lot trickier (because the `Challenge` event is not called in this case). One option might be to subclass the JWT bearer handler as suggested by @Set and to override `HandleForbiddenAsync` to do the right thing. Hopefully, it will be improved in the next version: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/issues/872.

Comment: That's a pity. Is there a good reason why `app.UseStatusCodePages()` wouldn't be used for 403s?

Comment: @davenewza oops, for some reasons, I missed your question, sorry. Actually, you can use the status code pages middleware (I updated my answer), but you have no way to determine what's causing the 403 response, so you can only return a very generic error message, which won't probably be really helpful for the users of your API.

Comment: Is it possible to just return a `IActionResult` instead?

Comment: `app.UseStatusCodePages()` has an overload that allows you to replay the request with a different path. So yes, you could handle that in a controller action and return an `IActionResult`.

Comment: Apparently `IApplicationBuilder` doesn't have a `UseStatusCodePages()` method!

Comment: I ended up using your first approach and customized the Response object manually. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, order of [middlewares](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/middleware.html) is important.

> Each middleware chooses whether to pass the request on to the next component in the pipeline, and can perform certain actions before and after the next component is invoked in the pipeline

UseJwtBearerAuthentication stops further pipeline execution if error occurred.

But your approach does not work with JwtBearerAuthentication middleware, as when you have unauthorized error, middleware sends WWWAuthenticate header, that why you get "response has already started" exception -  look into [HandleUnauthorizedAsync](https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer/JwtBearerHandler.cs#L186) method. You can override this method and implement your own custom logic.

Another possible solution (not sure that works) is to use `HttpContext.Response.OnStarting` callback in your middleware, as it is called before header send. You cal look on this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37920005/2833802)

Comment: "System.InvalidOperationException: Headers are read-only, response has already started" is thrown if placed before UseJwtBearerAuthentication.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you write to the httpContext.Response, and call next.Invoke(context), that is where the problem starts: because you already started a response (leading to Response.HasStarted = true), you are not allowed to set the StatusCode anymore.
Solution to fix, follow code below:

```
if (!context.Response.HasStarted)
        {
            try
            {
                await _next.Invoke(context);
            }
        }
```

Check HasStarted before pass request to next middleware